# Is it possible to cut a String from a specific word to another?

Tags: java, string

I have a long text that i want to cut into pieces. In the text there are unique sections i can use to identify one piece. Ive looked into this 
`TestString = TestString.Substring(0,TestString.IndexOf('-')).Trim()` 
but this only allows for one character and I need 10 so it wont work. The String I want to start cutting and to stop looks like this:

> "12.32.4214"

Has anyone found a souluion to this problem ?

Comment: on what basis you want to split the string? do you mean `split("-")`?

Comment: Provide the input and output strings and will help you

Comment: have you tried the `split` method in `String`?

Comment: Your comments that there are "unique sections i can use to identify one piece" makes me think that you probably want use Regular Expressions to locate your "specific word" (In RegEx terminology this would be a matching group).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are asking if you can use indexOf() to identify a 10 length sequence in your string.

Yes, you can.

```
int indexOf(String str)
```

You can search by a string in this way

```
TestString = TestString.Substring(0,TestString.IndexOf('-234265789')).Trim()
```